# XML Errors/ Android SDK

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get my Google Map in Android to show me my lcoation. Java is showing no errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error is showing that `xmlns` is apparently invalid for the fragment tag. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xmlns:android attribute is a namespace declaration and only should be on the root layout in your XML file.

Comment: IOW, delete `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your `<fragment>` element.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's sorta fixed it, no errors, but the app just crashes... back to the drawing board.

Comment: @JordanMoffat: Use LogCat to look at the stack trace associated with your crash. Then, ask a fresh SO question if you still cannot figure out the source of your difficulty.

Comment: @CommonsWare fixed it now, was an unrelated problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try including this in your fragment

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```